# How to add virtual directories in iis express?

Tags: web-applications, iis-express, applicationhost

I have hosted my web application and it’s sub-applications(virtual directories) in IIS Express and everything working fine. Here i have created applicationhost.config file at this %temp%\iisexpress location.

Instead of creating config file at temp location, I have added the entries in the config file which is present at this location ‘Documents\IISExpress\config’. But while launching the application, am getting the below exception

[image]

applicationhost.config file entries:
[image]

How to resolve this issue? Or how to add sub-applications (virtual directories) to the main application in IIS Express?

Comment: 2nd-4th bindings are in invalid format. Reverted all your change and use a tool such as Jexus Manager to modify the file, https://JexusManager.com

Answer (score 0):

**For configuring the main application:**

appcmd add site /name:"" /bindings:""

**For sub-applications:**

appcmd add app /site.name:"" /path:"" /physicalPath:"" /applicationPool:""